# JavaFX - Keep button disabled until a row in TableView is selected

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TableView in my program, as well as a button underneath it that I want to stay disabled until any of the rows in the TableView are selected. I've researched into it, but couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: Something like this: `button.disableProperty().bind(tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you, @anko - Do you want to reply to the thread, so I can mark it as best answer?

Comment: You are welcome. Not needed, but thank you! This was a quick answer, I would feel dirty! :))